# The use of 'in' or 'of' when referring to a change in role

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

It seems to me that the use of 'in' rather than 'of' is better in the sentence below but I am struggling to explain why.

> It presents a change in China's role in the Middle East.

or

> It presents a change of China's role in the Middle East.

Comment: To me, they are different in scope. A change _in_ a role says that the role is basically the same, but some details have changed. A chane _of_ a role says that the role has been replaced by a new role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a change in**  something:

Examples:

- a change in the schedule
- a change in the weather
- a change in behavior
- a change in China's role
- a change in John's attitude
- changes in behavior
- changes in attitude

**All of the above imply an existing thing in which a change occurs.**

Examples:

- a change of heart
- a change of scenery
- a change of clothes
- a change of guards

**All the above imply that the nouns (heart, scenery, clothes) are replaced by another object of the same category.**

Answer (score 0):

> It represents a change in China' role in the Middle East.

is idiomatic. If the repetition of "in" bothers you stylistically, you can try

> It changes China's role in the Middle East.

If you are really talking about symbols, so "represents" is necessary, you can try

> It represents China's changed role in the Middle East.

Edited to correspond to the edited question.

Comment: I apologize. I had written the two sentences incorrectly and have now changed them accordingly.